# finding constant of integration ODE

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following differential equation:

$\frac {\dot{y}} {\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}} = c$

The solution should be

$\dot{y} = a$

now I need a way of expressing a in terms of c, I'm looking for a function like $a=f(c)$

Answer (score 3):

$$\frac{\dot y}{\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}} = c\implies \frac{\dot{y}^2}{1+\dot{y}^2}=c^2\implies \dot{y}^2=\frac{c^2}{1-c^2}\implies \color{blue}{\dot{y} = \frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}=a}$$

Comment: If you look closely, in this case the correct answer is $y'=\frac{c}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$, because only one disambiguation of $\lvert y'\rvert=\frac{\lvert c\rvert}{\sqrt{1-c^2}}$ is admissible given the stronger hypothesis you have at the start.

Comment: @Gae.S. Yep! Thanks, the sign of $\dot{y}$ depends on $c$